# Can we use machine learning models to parametrize a family of functions

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose a parametrized family of functions is defined as $f(Z) = g$ where $g$ is mapping such that $g: X \rightarrow Y$.

Now the problem can be stated as follows:

Given inputs [$X_1, X_2,$ ... $X_n$] and responses [$Y_1, Y_2,$ ... $Y_n$] generated from $g_1, g_2,$ ... $g_n$; want to obtain the parameters such that $f(Z_1) = g_1, f(Z_2) = g_2,$ ... $f(Z_n) = g_n$ using supervised learning.

I wonder if there are related works or if this is not doable currently. Appreciate any insight!

Comment: Does this translate to a system of equations that have a larger number of unknowns than the number of equations themselves?

Comment: I don't think so. This is like learning a generalized functional relationships, where we can represent each of them using a set of parameters Z. But the actual input contains both and X and Y evaluate on lots of points; they will be pretty large.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. From a ML perspective in any case there would be restrictions on the family of functions, otherwise the hypothesis space is not even representable, so I think the answer would depend on which restrictions are applied, there would probably be some simple cases where the problem is solvable. I think this could also be related to some theoretical questions about the enumerability of the hypothesis space but this is above my pay grade ;)